# SQL error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and can't get this to work:

```
select z.[zip] as [ZIP],
z.[city] as [City],
z.[state] as [State],
z.[county] as [County],
lp.[value] as [Geomarket Short],
lp2.[value] as [Geomarket Long]
from world.dbo.[zip] z
left outer join [lookup.prompt] lp on (lp.[index] = z.[zip]) and (lp.[key] = 
'geomarket_zip')
left outer join [lookup.prompt] lp2 on (lp.[value] = lp2.[index]) and (lp2.
[key] = 'geomarket')
order by z.[zip]
```

I get this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

When I remove the order by clause, I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: remove the brackets - you don't need them when you're joining

Comment: Is this your entire query? I suspect there is more

Comment: personal advice: try to format your SQL-statements
have a look at http://www.sqlstyle.guide/
proper formated SQL statements are make trouble shooting & all futher changes easier for you and your fellows

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  z.zip AS [ZIP] ,
        z.city AS [City] ,
        z.state AS [State] ,
        z.county AS [County] ,
        lp.value AS [Geomarket Short] ,
        lp2.value AS [Geomarket Long]
FROM    world.dbo.zip z
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [lookup.prompt] lp ON lp.index = z.zip
                                              AND lp.key = 'geomarket_zip'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [lookup.prompt] lp2 ON lp.value = lp2.index
                                               AND lp2.key = 'geomarket'
ORDER BY z.zip;
```